# Is there a better way to install drush on Bluehost?

Tags: drush

I registered Bluehost, because they are recommended by drupal and because I wanted shell access for drush. I tried to install drush, but got some problems. Bluehostforum.com doesn't seem to be online anymore, that's why I'm asking here.

First I had to contact the support to enable the shell access and they did it. Composer was already installed. Then I tried

```
composer require drush/drush
```

and got this error message:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                                                                           
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: allow_url_fopen must be enabled in php.ini (https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found)
```

The used php.ini was somewhere in /opt/cpanel/... and read only. I set PHPRC to use the php.ini in my home directory:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
export PHPRC=/home/mydir/php.ini
```

Now there were extensions missing ('undefined function ...') which I added in php.ini:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
extension = phar.so
extension = json.so
extension = tokenizer.so
extension = ctype.so
extension = iconv.so
extension = simplexml.so
```

Finally drush was working. Is there a better way to do this? I.e. to add all the extensions in one step?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I found a much simpler and working solution with composer at this links:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2471553

https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

There was an older composer already installed and read only, so I downloaded a newer one and created an alias in .bashrc:

```
# curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
# mv composer.phar ~/bin/composer.phar
# alias composer="php ~/bin/composer.phar"
# composer -V 
# composer diagnose
# composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction
```

Comment: This worked so darn well. I spent an hour with tech support at BH and finally found this. Thank you.

Comment: Damn dude. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can install drush via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)

When you you have `Homebrew` installed you shall prepare for drush by running

`brew install git` and
`brew update`
After that you can just type

> brew tap homebrew/dupes
>
> brew tap homebrew/versions
>
> brew tap homebrew/php
>
> brew install drush

Comment: Thank you. I installed linuxbrew and then used your commands. But when installing drush I get this "Error: Permission denied - /usr/bin/gcc".

Comment: Have you tried run command as superuser `sudo`?

Comment: With sudo I get "sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?".

Comment: What to you get if you type `brew --version`

Comment: Try run `chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo` as root, and try install drush again

Comment: Try see this link if it doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607003/sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-sudo-installed-setuid-root

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in my situation, but thanks anyway.

Comment: OK I'm not so experienced in linux either :)